# Error 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elasticsearch-synonym

I am upgrading my solr version in existing application from solr 7.3.1 to 8.11.2. After upgrade my lucene synonyms stopped working and getting error

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Error 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>URI:</th>
            <td>/solr/emt/search</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>STATUS:</th>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>MESSAGE:</th>
            <td>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SERVLET:</th>
            <td>default</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>CAUSED BY:</th>
            <td>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Caused by:</h3>
    <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queries/function/BoostedQuery
    at com.github.healthonnet.search.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParser.applySynonymQueries(SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.java:409)
    at com.github.healthonnet.search.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParser.attemptToApplySynonymsToQuery(SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.java:393)
    at com.github.healthonnet.search.SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParser.parse(SynonymExpandingExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:162)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:334)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)
    at dinom.solr.CustomSearchHandler.handleJsonRequest(CustomSearchHandler.java:172)
    at dinom.solr.CustomSearchHandler.handleRequest(CustomSearchHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2637)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:791)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:564)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
</pre>

</body>
```

Following is my postman request body

```
{
  "path" : [ "/content/nitu", "https://blogs.nitu.com", "https://www.nitu.com/smarterwithnitu", "https://blogsqa.nitu.com", "/content/nitu-events" ],
  "swg" : "0",
  "dedupe" : "true",
  "query" : "4G",
  "client" : "user-search",
  "rows" : 20,
  "lang" : [ "*" ]
}
```

I am hitting http://localhost:8983/solr/nitu/search on postman.

I am a newbie to solr.

Comment: From Lucene 7.4.0 the BoostedQuery has been deprecated as you can see here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/queries/deprecated-list.html
Do you have any custom plugin using boostedQueries? Can you please share also the solrconfig and schema?

Comment: yes @Seasers, Iam using custom plugin with this. As of now I have taken the source code of hon-lucene-synonyms  plugin remove the boosted Query code and replaced it with FunctionScoreQuery and made the jar then I am using it. I want your idea on this. can we replace hon-lucene-synonyms with any other plugin?

Comment: Do you really need this plugin for synonym expansion in Solr? Why don't you use the default `SynonymGraphFilterFactory` available in Lucene 8.11?